# What is the difference between these two statements in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, heap-memory

```
int[] X = {1,2,3}; 
int[] Y = new int[] {1,2,3}
```

Will the content of array X also be stored on heap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference is that the first statement works only when the array variable is declared, while the second can be written separately from the declaration :

```
int[] X;
int[] Y;
X = {1,2,3}; // doesn't work
Y = new int[] {1,2,3}; // works
```

Answer (score 0):

These two statements are technically grammatically different but have identical effects.

An [array initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) can appear as part of a local variable declaration initializer as in:

```
int[] X = {1,2,3};
```

and also an array creation expression as in:

```
new int[] {1,2,3}
```

And yes, `X` will be on the heap. All objects in Java are on the heap and since arrays are objects, all arrays are on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Java provides a ease of initializing arrays. So with out new operator you can directly assign value. Like

```
 int[] X={1,2,3};
```

Here the size of array is know by no.of elements in the initialization block.

Another way of initializing is using new operator.

```
int[] y=new int[]{1,2,3};
```

String variable also uses the both the way of initialization. But in Strings these two types have different meaning.